# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when adding property to a groovy class

Tags: java, groovy

I have java legacy code which loads a groovy script and adds two properties into the loaded class. It works fine with groovy 1.7.0 but when I try to upgrade groovy to the version 1.8.0 or later it causes stable error "General error during class generation: -1 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1".
I’ve tried using groovy-all jar but result was the same with either Spring 2.5.6 or 3.2.11. Below is a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

A short test which reproduces the error. It’s interesting that error doesn’t occur when adding a simple property (attrSingle) but only when adding a list (attrList).

EDITED (added getting of the properties)

```
import groovy.lang.*;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.*;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.*;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement;
import org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.GeneratorContext;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.util.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class TestGroovyAutonomous {

    @Test
    public void testParsing() throws Exception {
      SimpleCustomizedGroovyClassLoader customizedGroovyClassLoader = new SimpleCustomizedGroovyClassLoader(new GroovyClassLoader());
      Class<?> groovyClass;
      try {
        groovyClass = customizedGroovyClassLoader.parseClass(new GroovyCodeSource(
                "{fact -> fact.a != null}",
                customizedGroovyClassLoader.generateScriptName(),
                "/scriptSandbox"));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error loading class");
        throw e;
      }
      assertTrue(groovyClass != null);
      GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();

      Boolean attrSingle = (Boolean) groovyObject.getProperty("attrSingle");
      System.out.println("Single=" + attrSingle);

      List<String> attrList = new ArrayList<String>();
      Object[] objects = (Object[]) groovyObject.getProperty("attrList");
        for (Object o : objects)
            attrList.add((String) o);
      System.out.println("List=" + attrList);        
    }

    class SimpleCustomizedGroovyClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader {
        public SimpleCustomizedGroovyClassLoader(ClassLoader cl) {
            super(cl);
        }

        @Override
        protected CompilationUnit createCompilationUnit(CompilerConfiguration config, CodeSource source) {
            CompilationUnit cu = super.createCompilationUnit(config, source);
            cu.addPhaseOperation(new CompilationUnit.PrimaryClassNodeOperation() {
                public void call(SourceUnit sourceUnit, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode classNode) throws CompilationFailedException {

                    classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(new ExpressionStatement(new MethodCallExpression(
                            VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, "setProperty",
                            new ArgumentListExpression(new ConstantExpression("attrSingle"),
                                                       new ConstantExpression(true)))));

                    ArgumentListExpression argumentListExpression = new ArgumentListExpression();
                    for (String attributeName : Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
                        argumentListExpression.addExpression(new ConstantExpression(attributeName));
                    classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(new ExpressionStatement(new MethodCallExpression(
                            VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, "setProperty",
                            new ArgumentListExpression(new ConstantExpression("attrList"), argumentListExpression))));
                }
            }, Phases.CONVERSION);
            return cu;
        }
    }
}
```

And error text:

```
index problem in script1000001.groovy
Error loading class

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: -1

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.remove(OperandStack.java:199)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.replace(OperandStack.java:270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:334)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:292)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:655)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:75)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(StatementWriter.java:599)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitExpressionStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:501)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:155)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:447)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:311)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructor(AsmClassGenerator.java:383)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1054)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:172)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:770)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:970)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:548)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:503)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:302)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:267)
    at x.y.TestGroovyAutonomous.testParsing(TestGroovyAutonomous.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

But with groovy 1.7.0 this test prints:

```
     Single=true
     List=[a, b, c]
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried updating to a version newer than February 2013?

Comment: Running this sample with `2.3.6` results in `BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'script1000002.groovy' Error while popping argument from operand stack tracker in class script1000002 method void <init>().`

Comment: Yes, getting the same error with groovy-all 2.3.7 as Opal says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really tell what you are trying to do but instead of this...

```
ArgumentListExpression argumentListExpression = new ArgumentListExpression();
for (String attributeName : Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
    argumentListExpression.addExpression(new ConstantExpression(attributeName));
classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(new ExpressionStatement(new MethodCallExpression(
                        VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, "setProperty",
                        new ArgumentListExpression(new ConstantExpression("attrList"), argumentListExpression))));
```

Does this yield the behavior you are after?...

```
ArgumentListExpression argumentListExpression = new ArgumentListExpression();
argumentListExpression.addExpression(new ConstantExpression("attrList"))
for (String attributeName : Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
    argumentListExpression.addExpression(new ConstantExpression(attributeName));
classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(new ExpressionStatement(new MethodCallExpression(
                        VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, "setProperty", argumentListExpression)));
```

EDIT

```
package grails.boot;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;
import groovy.lang.GroovyCodeSource;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;

import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassHelper;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArrayExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstantExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression;
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement;
import org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.GeneratorContext;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.Phases;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit;
import org.junit.Test;

public class GroovyTestAutonomous {

    @Test
    public void testParsing() throws Exception {
        SimpleCustomizedGroovyClassLoader customizedGroovyClassLoader = new SimpleCustomizedGroovyClassLoader(new GroovyClassLoader());
        Class<?> groovyClass;
        try {
            groovyClass = customizedGroovyClassLoader.parseClass(new GroovyCodeSource(
                    "{fact -> fact.a != null}",
                    customizedGroovyClassLoader.generateScriptName(),
                    "/scriptSandbox"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading class");
            throw e;
        }
        assertTrue(groovyClass != null);
        GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();

        Boolean attrSingle = (Boolean) groovyObject.getProperty("attrSingle");
        System.out.println("Single=" + attrSingle);

        List<String> attrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Object[] objects = (Object[]) groovyObject.getProperty("attrList");
        for (Object o : objects)
            attrList.add((String) o);
        System.out.println("List=" + attrList);
    }

    class SimpleCustomizedGroovyClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader {
        public SimpleCustomizedGroovyClassLoader(ClassLoader cl) {
            super(cl);
        }

        @Override
        protected CompilationUnit createCompilationUnit(CompilerConfiguration config, CodeSource source) {
            CompilationUnit cu = super.createCompilationUnit(config, source);
            cu.addPhaseOperation(new CompilationUnit.PrimaryClassNodeOperation() {
                        public void call(SourceUnit sourceUnit, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode classNode) throws CompilationFailedException {

                            classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(new ExpressionStatement(new MethodCallExpression(
                                    VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, "setProperty",
                                    new ArgumentListExpression(new ConstantExpression("attrSingle"),
                                    new ConstantExpression(true)))));

                            List<Expression> args = new ArrayList<Expression>();
                            ArgumentListExpression argumentListExpression = new     ArgumentListExpression();
                            argumentListExpression.addExpression(new ConstantExpression("attrList"));
                            for (String attributeName : Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
                                args.add(new ConstantExpression(attributeName));

                            ArrayExpression arrayExpression = new ArrayExpression(ClassHelper.make(Object.class), args);
                            argumentListExpression.addExpression(arrayExpression);
                            classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(new ExpressionStatement(new MethodCallExpression(
                                    VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, "setProperty", argumentListExpression)));
                        }
                    }, Phases.CONVERSION);
            return cu;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In another place I read these properties:

        GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();

        Boolean attrSingle = (Boolean) groovyObject.getProperty("attrSingle");
 
        List<String> attrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Object[] objects = (Object[]) groovyObject.getProperty("attrList");
            for (Object o : objects)
                attrList.add((String) o);

Comment: Unfortunately, with your code I get the following error:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: script1000001.setProperty() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [attrList, a, b, c]
Possible solutions: setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), getProperty(java.lang.String), getProperty(java.lang.String), getProperties()...

Comment: Are you trying to generate code which invokes the `setProperty` method and passes a `String` as the first argument and a `Object[]` as the second argument?

Comment: Or a `List` as the second argument?  Something else?

Comment: It's a legacy but still working Java code which 1) loads a class from the groovy script 2) adds to the loaded class TWO properties: one named "attrSingle" of boolean type and one named "attrList" which is a list of strings 3) occasionally creates instance of the loaded class and reads these two properties 4) performs the groovy script (omitted in my test).

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you are doing.  The test I posted in an edit above passes but that may not be what you are looking for.  I am sorry that I wasn't able to help.  Best of luck.

Comment: I've added getting of properties to the sample so that it was clearer. Thank you for your attempt, Jeff!

Comment: That makes it more clear.  I have added a version of your code that passes your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Jeff, it works both with 1.7.0 and higher versions.

The following code which is a little closer to the initial version works too:

```
               List<Expression> args = new ArrayList<Expression>();
                for (String attributeName : Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
                    args.add(new ConstantExpression(attributeName));
                ArrayExpression arrayExpression = new ArrayExpression(ClassHelper.make(Object.class), args);

                classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(new ExpressionStatement(new MethodCallExpression(
                        VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, "setProperty",
                        new ArgumentListExpression(new ConstantExpression("attrList"), arrayExpression))));
```

Moreover, we can just replace ArgumentListExpression in the original code with ListExpression:

```
                ListExpression args = new ListExpression();
                for (String attributeName : Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))
                    args.addExpression(new ConstantExpression(attributeName));

                classNode.addObjectInitializerStatements(new ExpressionStatement(new MethodCallExpression(
                        VariableExpression.THIS_EXPRESSION, "setProperty",
                        new ArgumentListExpression(new ConstantExpression("attrList"), args))));
```

in pair with a change in the extractor code:

```
    List<String> attrList = (ArrayList<String>) groovyObject.getProperty("attrList");
    System.out.println("List=" + attrList);
```

As far as I understand, since version 1.8.0 the ArgumentListExpression does not accept an argument of the same type (ArgumentListExpression), it must be of type ListExpression or ArrayExpression, at least for the setProperty method to work.